# how can I force href direction to external host page?

Tags: html, url, href

I have this html:

```
<a href="http:/myhost.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.1052,42.3261,-71.0872,42.3354,-71.0570,42.3295,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0754,42.3311,-71.0617,42.3428,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0675,42.3525,-71.0376,42.3395)">live map</a>
```

I open it in my browser, as follows:

http://localhost:63342/RoutingRegression/html_pages/delta_to_baseline_table/delta_to_baseline_samples_agg_fresh.html#astar_improve

and when I press the link I'm direct to:

```
http://localhost:63342/myhost.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.1052,42.3261,-71.0872,42.3354,-71.0570,42.3295,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0754,42.3311,-71.0617,42.3428,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0675,42.3525,-71.0376,42.3395)
```

how can i change it to be directed to: (new http page):

```
"http:/myhost.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.1052,42.3261,-71.0872,42.3354,-71.0570,42.3295,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0754,42.3311,-71.0617,42.3428,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0675,42.3525,-71.0376,42.3395)"
```

**Update**

how can it be that it's generated "http:/" instead of "http://" ?

this is my url builder:

```
    UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
            .fromPath(Constants.LIVEMAP_BASE_URL_US)
            .scheme("http");
    return builder.build().toString();
```

Comment: if you want a new browser window, you need to add target="_blank"in your a tag. And the url should be http://...

Answer (score 3):

It seems your url is incorrect

change

```
http:/myhost.com
```

to be

```
http://myhost.com
```

Comment: I don't know what is the `UriBuilder`, it's java I guess. It will return `http:/myhost.com/...` with one slash, it's the way `UriBuilder` works I guess.
Try this `return new URL(builder.build().toString());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put double // in your url like this:

```
http://myhost.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.1052,42.3261,-71.0872,42.3354,-71.0570,42.3295,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0754,42.3311,-71.0617,42.3428,-71.0376,42.3394),(-71.1208,42.3317,-71.0675,42.3525,-71.0376,42.3395)
```